# agent.add not working inside promise.then dialogflow

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

```
     function issuetype(agent) {
    
          //let i = 0;
       console.log('inside issuetype');
          return admin.database().ref('Support/issuetype').once('value', function(snapshot) {
    
              var data = snapshot.val(); 
              var array = Object.values(data);
            console.log('Issues are');
            console.log(array);
            agent.add(`Select your issue `);  //works fine
            for(const val of array){
              agent.add(new Suggestion(`${val}`)); 
            }
                console.log(data);
          });
       }

   function subtype(agent) {

    let data;
    let value;
    let id;
    console.log('inside subtype');
     let harry = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
       admin.database().ref('Support/issuetype').once('value', function(snapshot) {
            value = agent.parameters.sub;
            console.log('inside promise');
            data = snapshot.val(); 
            console.log('Key'+Object.keys(data));
            console.log('Value'+value);
            id = Object.keys(data).find(key => data[key] === value);
            console.log('Matched id');
            console.log(id);
           if(id){
             resolve(id);strong text
           }else{
           reject('not resolved');
           }
      });
    });
    
     harry.then(function(res){
        console.log('Type of id:'+typeof(res));
        console.log('id is:'+res);
        agent.add(`Select your sub issue ret`);
       admin.database().ref('Support/issuesubtype/'+res).once('value', function(snap) {
            var snapdata = snap.val(); 
            var values = Object.values(snapdata);
            console.log(typeof(values));  
            console.log('SubIssues are'); // displayed in console
            console.log(values);
            agent.add(`Select your sub issue `); // not displayed
            return agent.add(`Select your sub issue `); // not displayed
           for(const k of values){
            agent.add(new Suggestion(`${k}`)); // not displayed
           }
        });  
    }).catch(function(rej){
        console.log(rej);**strong text**
    }).then(function(rej){
        console.log('Irrespctive');
    });

   }
intentMap.set('issuetype', issuetype);
intentMap.set('subtype', subtype);
```

Function subtype is called by intentMap,
And inside it harry function returns a promise, once promise is resolved I am getting data from firebase and want to display it using agent.add
Getting expected output in console.log but agent.add is blank
Whereas agent.add is working in issuetype function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you're mixing Promises and callbacks, sometimes returning the Promise, and sometimes not. It is easiest if you keep a few guidelines in mind:

- Make sure you return the Promise.
- Make sure your call to `agent.add()` is inside the `.then()` clause.
- If you're using callback functions, those can be switched to using Promises instead in most cases.

Keep in mind that you don't need to wrap this into a new Promise, since the Firebase calls you're making return a Promise if you don't give it a callback function.

For example, your line

```
admin.database().ref('Support/issuesubtype/'+res).once('value', function(snap) {
```

should probably better be rewritten as

```
return admin.database().ref('Support/issuesubtype/'+res).once('value')
  .then( snap => {
```

The important points here are that you're returning the Promise and you're using a Promise instead of a callback to handle the function.

Comment: Works like a charm! Without the `return` before promise, agent lines don't work inside `then`. Am new to JS, can you explain why this is happening?

Comment: The short answer is because you need to return the Promise so the calling function knows to wait for the result before continuing. Otherwise it will make the network call, but not wait for the reply. Read up on how Promise works and how async/await work.